# Rails Ajax 505 error and cache [POST :action] invalidate, pass error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

im trying to post data by ajax to a rails controller. But i am getting a 505 internal server error and in my logs im getting a 'cache [POST :action] invalidate, pass error. Here is my code.

ajax code:

```
 send: function(){
  if (notification.isValid() === false){
    return false;
  }
  var eventId = parseInt(window._eventId, 10),
      textarea = $('.sendNotificationTextarea'),
      text = textarea.val(),
      token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
  $.ajax({
    url: '/cardboard/events/notify',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      text: text,
      event_id: eventId,
      emails: notification.getUsersEmails()
    },
    success: function(){
      $('.flashNotify').show().fadeOut(3000);
      textarea.val('');
    }
  });
}
```

my routes:

```
post '/cardboard/events/notify', to: 'cardboard/events#notify'
```

controller:

```
  def notify
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    description = "Notification about #{event.name}: #{params[:text]}"
    users = User.find_all_by_email(params[:emails])
    Notification.notify(users, description)
    render nothing: true, status: :ok
  end
```

I tried generating csrf tags and sending them through my headers but that didnt work either.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: this might help you find the problem: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but should use 'match' instead of 'post' in your routes

match '/cardboard/events/notify', to: 'cardboard/events#notify'